# jquery post submit prevent validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

i can prevent validation on my form by adding the cancel class to the submit button.
in some case i want to post the form with a jquery `$("#myForm").ajax` with type : post and the validation process is also triggered. how can i prevent validation from occurring in this case ? ("get" is not an option)

Comment: can you explain "how can i prevent validation from occurring 'in this case' ?".

Comment: when i use jquery ajax to submit my form